# TTL of cach using MongoDB in mule

Tags: mongodb, caching, mule

I configured in mule object-store-caching-strategy that working with MongoDB.

`<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="MongoDB_Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
        <spring-object-store ref="MongoDB_object_store" />
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>`

Used with spring:

`<spring:bean id="MongoDB_object_store" class="org.mule.module.mongo.MongoObjectStore" init-method="initialize" scope="singleton">
            <spring:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
            <spring:property name="port" value="27017"/>
            <spring:property name="database" value="test"/>
            <spring:property name="username" value="test"/>
             <spring:property name="writeConcern" value="DATABASE_DEFAULT"/>
        </spring:bean>`

I want to set up the TTL for cache.

Where do I need to do that?

EDIT:

I added class "ExpirableMongoObjectStore" -

```
public class ExpirableMongoObjectStore<T extends Serializable> extends MongoObjectStore {

/**
 * The maxEntries of the Mongo cache
 */
@Optional
@DefaultValue("-1")
private int maxEntries;

/**
 * The maxEntries of the Mongo cache
 */
@Optional
@DefaultValue("600000")
private int entryTTL;

/**
 * The maxEntries of the Mongo cache
 */
@Optional
@DefaultValue("1000")
private int expirationInterval;

private MongoClient mongoClient;
private static final String TIMESTAMP_FIELD = "timestamp";
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());

public void setEntryTTL(int entryTTL) {this.entryTTL = entryTTL; }
public void setExpirationInterval(int expirationInterval) { this.expirationInterval = expirationInterval;}
public void setMaxEntries(int maxEntries){this.maxEntries = maxEntries; }
public int getEntryTTL(){ return entryTTL;} 
public int getExpirationInterval() {return expirationInterval;}
public int getMaxEntries() { return maxEntries;}

protected ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, StoredObject<T>> store;
public ExpirableMongoObjectStore()
{

         this.store = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<Long, StoredObject<T>>();
         logger.debug("ddd");
}

@Override
public void expire(int entryTTL, int maxEntries) throws ObjectStoreException        
{
    //Option 1:
        /*if ((entryTTL > 0))
        {
            final long now = System.nanoTime();
            int expiredEntries = 0;
            Map.Entry<?, ?> oldestEntry;

            purge:
            while ((oldestEntry = store.firstEntry()) != null)
            {
                Long oldestKey = (Long) oldestEntry.getKey();
                long oldestKeyValue = oldestKey.longValue();

                if (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(now - oldestKeyValue) >= entryTTL)
                {
                    store.remove(oldestKey);
                    expiredEntries++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break purge;
                }
            }

            if (logger.isDebugEnabled())
            {
                logger.debug("Expired " + expiredEntries + " old entries");
            }
        }*/

    //Option 2:
        super.expire(getEntryTTL(), getMaxEntries());

    //Option 3:
        /*final String partitionName = "OBJECTSTORE_DEFAULT_PARTITION_NAME";

        final String collection = getCollectionName(partitionName);
        final long expireAt = System.currentTimeMillis() - entryTTL;
        final DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start(TIMESTAMP_FIELD).lessThan(expireAt).get();
        mongoClient.removeObjects(collection, query, getWriteConcern());*/
}

protected static class StoredObject<T>
{
    private Serializable id;
    private T item;

    public StoredObject(Serializable id, T item)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.item = item;
    }

    public Serializable getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public T getItem()
    {
        return item;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (this == o)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass())
        {
            return false;
        }

        StoredObject<T> that = (StoredObject<T>) o;
        if (!id.equals(that.id))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return id.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("StoredObject");
        sb.append("{id='").append(id).append('\'');
        sb.append(", item=").append(item);
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

There are 3 options in 'expire' method, how to implement it.
I don't know, which is prefer.
and with every one from them it seems it's not work - expire method isn't runnig.
Someone do you know why? what is problem?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="MongoDB_Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
    <spring-object-store ref="MongoDB_object_store" entryTTL="200"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

HTH

Comment: Although I think that only applies to ```in-memory-object-store```.

Answer (score 0):

`InMemoryObjectStore` inherits from http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/util/store/AbstractMonitoredObjectStore.html which allows you to set the `entryTTL`.

Whereas `MongoObjectStore` doesn't.

You could try extending `MongoobjectStore` and adding an `entryTTL` field. Then override the expire method from `org.mule.api.store.PartitionableExpirableObjectStore` which is already implemented by `MongoObjectStore`. You can try using the same logic from the expire method in the `InMemoryObjectStore` class: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.5.0/org/mule/util/store/InMemoryObjectStore.java#InMemoryObjectStore.expire%28%29

Comment: thanks, If you can show me with example code what do you mean, it very help me.

Comment: I meaning  - Do I need to do it in xml or create class?

Comment: Create a Java class and extend it. public class ExpirableMongoObjectStore extends MongoObjectStore

Comment: But there is 'expire' function in MongoObjectStore - public void expire(final int entryTtl, final int ignoredMaxEntries, final String partitionName)
        throws ObjectStoreException
    {
        final String collection = getCollectionName(partitionName);
        final long expireAt = System.currentTimeMillis() - entryTtl;
        final DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start(TIMESTAMP_FIELD).lessThan(expireAt).get();
        mongoClient.removeObjects(collection, query, getWriteConcern());
    }

Comment: Yep but override it, so you can set your own ttl. add a field for the ttl, override the expire method and call the existing expire method passing in your ttl.

Comment: I added class, but ot seems not working. I edited the question with details of class, I hope you will can help me. thanks.

Comment: I meaning, when is 'expire' method is active? when do we call to it?